# Where to begin to learn Bloomberg's distributed DB Comdb2?

Tags: database, bloomberg, distributed-database

I plan to learn from its source code about how it 
provides perfect availability,no concurrency, Single System Image.

Besides their wiki, is there any developer group where people could ask development related question?
Is there design document to help to understand implementation?
Is there any sample application that show how to use comdb2?

Comment: You can try to create an issue in their github and ask: https://github.com/bloomberg/comdb2/issues

Comment: https://github.com/bloomberg/comdb2/issues/310

Comment: Yes, I took the advice and created an issue in the repo.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the "[Comdb2 bloomberg's highly available relational database system](https://doi.org/10.14778/3007263.3007275)" paper.